# Does Halo 2 only work under Windows Vista?

Tags: pc, backwards-compatibility, halo-2

I have Halo 2 for Windows Vista and I'm considering upgrading to Windows 7.

Will Halo 2 run on Windows 7, or is it Windows Vista only?

***EDIT:*** An update on this post: I was not able to make it work on a Windows 7 system (as predicted by the Bungie post linked by @Sean). However, it installed and ran perfectly with no problems on a new Windows 8 laptop.

Comment: I have yet to get it to work on windows 7.  If this is possible, I would be interested... +1

Comment: Nope, it runs on my Xbox as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, though there is great potential for installation misery. The top entry of [the official Bungie FAQ](http://www.bungie.net/Forums/posts.aspx?postID=59880496):

> **Does Halo 2 Vista work with Windows 7 32-bit/64-bit?**
>
> Yes and no. Some people have issues, some people run the game fine. The only way to know is to try yourself.

If you do run into issues, try installing the latest patches (W7, GFWL, and *[H2](http://www.microsoft.com/games/halo2/)*) or [these workarounds](http://www.modacity.net/forums/showthread.php?22030-Windows-7-Walkarounds-%28Halo-2-for-Windows-Vista%29).

Comment: I feel indifferent about that answer from bungie.... [it] makes me sad panda